# Solr extract data from the index to a XML file

Tags: java, xml, csv, solr, lucene

We have the index files which are provided by the client and now want to reindex them by removing the duplicate documents

[Solr deduplication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication)

for this i have to read the data from the index and have to generate an **XML** file or **CSV** file and then index them with eliminating duplicates

(correct me if im wrong i didnt find any other way to do this)

I know this is possible using Lucene but i wanted to know how can i do this using solr

Comment: Have you considered how to access data that is indexed, but unstored, in the index?  Simply querying for all documents may not necessarily retrieve all of the data used to construct the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the export format by setting the `wt` parameter to xml
`...&wt=xml` at you Solr query.

This will export the results to xml. So if you search for * you will get the full content - depending on the `limit` parameter.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreQueryParameters#wt

That will also work with csv: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter

Comment: You can also add a xslt file to the link, so the data will be converted to a structure you want.